# Как отдебажить получаемый шаблон в Django

Tags: python, django, pytest, reverse

Не понимаю, почему не проходит тест шаблона. Падает ошибка: `AssertionError: No templates used to render the response`.

Содержимое объекта `response` из которого видно что в нем уже есть шаблон `products/index.html`:

[image: Содержимое объекта response]

Код `/store/products/tests.py`:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
import django
django.setup()


class IndexViewTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_view(self):
        path = reverse('index')
        response = self.client.get(path)

        print(response.template_name)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.context_data['title'], 'Store')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'products/index.html')
```

Здесь использую `import django` и `django.setup()` потому что падала ошибка:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Django требовал, чтобы `testserver` был добавлен в `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, что я и сделал:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'testserver']
```

Код `/store/products/views.py`:

```
class IndexView(TitleMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'products/index.html'
    title = 'Store'


class ProductsListView(TitleMixin, ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'products/products.html'
    paginate_by = 3
    title = 'Store - каталог'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ProductsListView, self).get_queryset()
        category_id = self.kwargs.get('category_id')
        return queryset.filter(category_id=category_id) if category_id else queryset

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductsListView, self).get_context_data()
        context['categories'] = ProductCategory.objects.all()
        return context
```

`/store/products/urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path

from products.views import ProductsListView, basket_add, basket_remove

app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProductsListView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('category/<int:category_id>/', ProductsListView.as_view(), name='category'),
    path('page/<int:page>/', ProductsListView.as_view(), name='paginator'),

    path('baskets/add/<int:product_id>/', basket_add, name='basket_add'),
    path('baskets/remove/<int:basket_id>/', basket_remove, name='basket_remove'),
]
```

Конфиг pytest:

[image: Конфиг pytest]

Пробовал запуск не pytest'ом, а обычной python-конфигурацией. Здесь тесты проходят:
[image: результаты запуск python-конфигурацией]

В этом случае конфиг был такой:
[image: конфиг запуска python-конфигурацией]

Пробовал использовать 2 варианта написания `reverse` чтобы явно указать, что хочу получить путь к представлению `index` в приложении `products` но не помог ни один из них:

```
reverse('products:index')

reverse('products:index', current_app='products')
```

Может быть дело в том, что в проекте существуют другие URL-шаблоны, которые имеют имя `index` и отличаются от пути, который соответствует представлению `IndexView`? Есть корневой urls, который тоже содержит `index`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('password_reset/', ResetPasswordView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('products/', include('products.urls', namespace='products')),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
    path('web/', include('web.urls')),
]
```